# Random Letters using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, aix

I am in the process of creating a sh code for masking the sensitive data using AWK function in AIX server.

```
Input:

CustomerName|somedata|phonenumber|Address
Roly|xyz|1234|London

Output:

CustomerName|somedata|phonenumber|Address
Atrm|xyz|8546|Xdfdtt
```

Note: CustomerName,Phonenumber,Address are sensitive so I change only those.

I want to keep the same dictionary values till I decide to change the dictionary ( what to replace for what).

My code in AIX. This will work in AIX system only (I hope so)

```
set -A randomalpha
set -A alphabets a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
set -A numbers 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
randomalpha=`cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc 'A-Z'|head -c 26`
randonumber=`cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc '0-9'|head -c 26`

i=0
echo $randomalpha | awk -v ORS="" '{ gsub(/./,"&\n") ; print }' | \
while read char
do
   randomalpha[i]="$char"
   print "$char"
   ((i=i+1))
done

print ${randomalpha[4]}
print ${alphabets[25]}

integer max=1400
integer i=1

while [[ $i -lt $max ]]
do
# $(echo value of is : $i >> $file)
 #   echo value i: $i
  #  (( i = i + 1 ))
b=""
echo "Please enter your name:" 
read name

i=0

echo $name | awk -v ORS=" " '{ gsub(/./,"&\n") ; print }' | \
while read char
do
   name[i]="$char"   

   j=0
    while [ $j -le 36 ] 
    do

    if [[ "$char" == ${alphabets[j]} ]];then
        #print  "matched here:"${alphabets[j]}"matched here:"${randomalpha[j]} 
        b=$b${randomalpha[j]}

        if [ -z "${char}" ];then
             b=$b${randomalpha[j]}" "
        fi

        if [[ "$char" == ${numbers[j]+} ]];then
           print "$char"
        #print  "matched here:"${alphabets[j]}"matched here:"${randomalpha[j]} 
        b=$b${randonumber[j]}

        if [ -z "${numbers}" ];then
             b=$b${randonumber[j]}" "
        fi
        fi

    fi
    ((j=j+1))
    done
   ((i=i+1))
done

print $b

done
```

What I have done is

I have assigned a random characters for A-Z and then matched the input value for each character and replaced with the dictionary value for that character.

In simple TERMS , let us say

Actual Value : ABCD
Random Generated : XUTY

so Anytime it finds A it will be replaced with X. 
I know it's a bad code but I was trying this option to prove that it's possible.

**Can somebody please throw some light on achieving the results using few lines AWK in simpler manner than a big code?**

This code is much slower when I handle 20GB files

Thanks!

Comment: And what is the problem?  Syntax, logic, not the output you are expecting, ...?  What does that code do that you do not like?

Comment: I just ran your code on AIX 6.1, works ok, I see 26 random letters and then it asks me for my name.  When I type something, it replaces the letters by the corresponding indexed capital letter.  So, what now...?

Comment: Same result on AIX 7.1.

Comment: Can somebody please throw some light on achieving the results using few lines AWK in simpler manner than a big code?

Comment: This is a very weak encryption, especially for phone numbers.  If you can guess one (known number for a person, area codes, unassigned number, etc), all can be decrypted.   I would suggest combining alpha and numeric into one symbol table.

Comment: Hopefully you noticed that `cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc 'A-Z'|head -c 26` doesn't usually produce 26 unique letters, some duplicates will probably exist, and so you could never map back to the original letters. idk if that's desirable or not but if it is what you want then you may as well map every letter to a `#` or  similar.

Comment: If you only need to obfuscate the data, replace all numbers by 0000 and all works by AAAA.  You need to "de-obfuscate" it (so it is both ways, hide data  and regenerate the true data from the hidden values) ?

Comment: Thanks NIC, I cannot replace it with same alpha numeric. say I have London and Paris, if I replace with  Aaaa, I would see single unique value but I have 2 values. My requirement is to show 2 distinct values. my original goal is to obfuscate and get the correct count.  thanks for your responses.

Comment: With your existing code London and Berlin could both end up as Aaaaaa since the "random" letters produced by your current action on /dev/random will almost certainly produce duplicates so you COULD in theory end up with every letter in both city names mapping to `A/a`. wrt `get the correct count` - if all you want is to have different length city names map to different numbers of letters then again you could just map every letter to `#` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, this will work with any awk on any system and will run orders of magnitude faster than your shell script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function shuffle(oldStr,        newStr,len,array,i,j,t) {
    # logic copied from https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#AWK
    # and tweaked to operate on a string as input instead of an array.
    len = length(oldStr)
    for (i=1; i<=len; i++) {
        array[i] = substr(oldStr,i,1)
    }

    for (i = len; i > 1; i--) {
        # j = random integer from 1 to i
        j = int(i * rand()) + 1

        # swap array[i], array[j]
        t = array[i]
        array[i] = array[j]
        array[j] = t
    }

    for (i=1; i<=len; i++) {
        newStr = newStr array[i]
    }
    return newStr
}

BEGIN {
    srand()

    ordrLets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    randLets = shuffle(ordrLets)
    ordrDigs = "0123456789"
    randDigs = shuffle(ordrDigs)

    ordrChars = ordrLets ordrDigs
    randChars = randLets randDigs

    numChars = length(ordrChars)
    for (charNr=1; charNr<=numChars; charNr++) {
        oldChar = substr(ordrChars,charNr,1)
        newChar = substr(randChars,charNr,1)
        map[tolower(oldChar)] = tolower(newChar)
        map[toupper(oldChar)] = toupper(newChar)
        # Uncomment this to print the mappings to stderr:
        # print oldChar, newChar | "cat>&2"
    }

    split("1 3 4", fldIdx2nr)

    FS = OFS = "|"
}

NR==1 { print; next }
{
    for (fldIdx in fldIdx2nr) {
        fldNr  = fldIdx2nr[fldIdx]
        oldStr = $fldNr
        newStr = ""
        numChars = length(oldStr)
        for (charNr=1; charNr<=numChars; charNr++) {
            oldChar = substr(oldStr,charNr,1)
            newChar = (oldChar in map ? map[oldChar] : oldChar)
            newStr  = newStr newChar
        }
        $fldNr = newStr
    }
    print
}
```

.

```
$ cat file
CustomerName|somedata|phonenumber|Address
Roly|xyz|1234|London

$ awk -f tst.awk file
CustomerName|somedata|phonenumber|Address
Tcnj|xyz|2397|Ncoyco
```

I assumed you actually want each letter to map to a unique letter, unlike what your original code did. If that's not the case and you don't mind multiple original letters mapping to the same final letter then you can use a simple call to rand() to create each individual mapping instead of using the main algorithm of the shuffle() function.

Comment: Ed, this works superb. Can you please explain in high level. So that I can have some good understanding. Thanks a million.

Comment: I actually think that despite being quite lengthy it's pretty self-explanatory so please read through it (add print statements to dump variables etc if necessary) and let me know if you have any specific questions. If you have any questions about the "shuffle" function, see the web page I referenced where I copied the main part of that functions code from.

Comment: map[tolower(oldChar)] = tolower(newChar)
map[toupper(oldChar)] = toupper(newChar)

Comment: I understood what the below lines are  trying to do but how it is doing is unclear. May be i didn't get right document to know map and the usage.  Please explain  on the below 3 lines.                                                                              map[tolower(oldChar)] = tolower(newChar)
 map[toupper(oldChar)] = toupper(newChar)                                                       newChar = (oldChar in map ? map[oldChar] : oldChar)

Comment: `map` is just an associative array, as all awk arrays are. I could have named it `bubbles` or `dilbert` or anything - nothing magic about the name. I'm using it to store a mapping from each character to a different character, e.g. `map["A"] = "D"; map["a"] = "d"`. So given any character "x" is that character exists as an index of map[] (`"x" in map`) then I set the new character to the value stored in `map["x"]` otherwise the new character remains as `"x"` (google `ternary expression`).

Comment: Now, I want to change the assignment for 2nd repeated character. Like if  London London is repeated twice then the repeated characters should get different assignment. I tried shuffle but the space is misaligned. I want to keep the space in same position and I want to shuffle the letters only. Please let me know if you have an idea for this

Comment: Ask a new question with it's own concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Sorry,My bad. I accidentally did it. Thanks for notifying me.